# How to tell maven-dependency-plugin that the artifact is used in the project?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-dependency-plugin

This is a structure of my multi-module project:

```
/root
  /api dependencies: slf4j
  /foo dependencies: slf4j-log4j12, log4j
```

In other words, module `api` uses `slf4j` for logging purposes. It doesn't know what the implementation of logging facility will be. Module `foo` adds `slf4j-log4j12` and `log4j` in order to implement the logging. Pretty simple.

Now I'm running `maven-dependency-plugin:analyze-only` and this is what it says for module `foo`:

```
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[WARNING]    log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
```

Meaning that the plugin doesn't understand that `foo` really needs these dependencies. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Why adding another module which manages dependencies when dependency management is done by Maven? It's Maven's strongest point

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What happens if you give those dependencies a `runtime` scope instead of `compile`?

If you've defined them as compile-time dependencies I think the dependency plugin will think they are needed for the compile when they're really not. But you only need the slf4-log4j and log4j JAR files at runtime.

**Edit:** You may need to set the `ignoreNonCompile` option:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html

Comment: Good idea, but the result is the same :(

Comment: @yegor256 I've just edited my answer. There is an 'ignoreNonCompile' flag on the analyze task, you may need to set that.

Comment: Strange 'ignoreNonCompile' doesn't default to true.

Comment: I'm wondering how analyze is done for the runtime scope. The docs only say: "anything that doesn't get into bytecode isn't detected. This is the case, for example, of constants, annotations with source retention policy, or javadoc links." But it's still interesting how it works for runtime at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the scope of `slf4j-log4j12` and `log4j` to runtime?
See [maven dependency scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)