# Maven dependency:analyze issues irritating warnings

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-3, dependency-management

I have a Maven module (part of a multi-module project) with the following dependency declared:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Classes from that package are used in the following way:

```
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
```

Everything compiles fine.

When I run `mvn dependency:analyze` (or `analyze-only`), the following warning is issued though:

```
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile
```

This seems to indicated that I could remove the said dependency, in particular because we want to set the `failOnWarning` option to `true`, the warning hence results in a build failure. However, the package is clearly required and when I remove it, the module fails to compile:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project mymodule: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] MyClass.java:[18,34] package org.apache.commons.logging does not exist
[ERROR] MyClass.java:[19,34] package org.apache.commons.logging does not exist
[ERROR] MyClass.java:[44,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Log
[ERROR] location: class MyClass
```

There are related questions around:

[Why were Spring Boot starter dependencies designed to be used contrary to the stated intent of Maven's transitive dependency mechanisms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994153/maven-dependencyanalyze-warnings-for-spring-boot-starter-transitive-dependencie),

[How to tell maven-dependency-plugin that the artifact is used in the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919297/how-to-tell-maven-dependency-plugin-that-the-artifact-is-used-in-the-project),

[Why is dependency:analyze lying to me?](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Why-is-dependency-analyze-lying-to-me-td5784108.html)

but they are either unanswered or the answers relate to problems with scope. In my case, the scope needs to be `compile` (i.e. no need to declare).

Comment: Which version of maven-dependency-plugin do you use?

Comment: You might use an other version from a transitive dependency...recheck with `mvn dependency:tree` and see if commons-logging is coming from another dependency...or an other module?

Comment: `maven-dependency-plugin` version is 2.10. There is indeed a transitive dependency on commons-logging in the tree, but with scope `test`. So it is not accessible on compile time.

Comment: Also, the transitive dependency on commons-logging is the same version: `[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:test`.

Comment: I just noticed that these are actually two different dependencies (the transitive one being `-api`. However, when I change the explicit dependency to `-api`, the project still compiles, but the warning persists.

Comment: Have you tried setting `ignoreNonCompile` for the plugin? (this allows not to modify the scope of the actual dependency)